# How to forward request to different endpoint in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have an endpoint that is singularly responsible for all form submissions; this endpoint then sends the data to the correct endpoint given to it by data in the form submission (from a hidden field for example).

I know where to send the data:

```
post to /account
```

How do I forward data received by the server to another endpoint on the same server directly with out a re-direct?

Or is the only way to use a HTTP client like curb or rest-client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look nice, but you can try something like this:

```
post "/account" do
  call! env.merge('PATH_INFO' => "/another/endpoint")
end

post "/another/endpoint" do
  ...
end
```

But generally it's better to extract whatever the code is in the `/another/endpoint` and call it directly from the `/account` endpoint. E.g:

```
post "/account" do
  process_data(...)
end

post "/another/endpoint" do
  process_data(...)
end

def process_data(...)
  ...
end
```